# Integrating a probability over a region with respect to a distribution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose we observe random variables $(X, Y)$, where the marginal distributions are $F_X, F_Y$, and $Y \in \{0, 1\}, X \subset \mathbb{R}^k$. Let $p(x) := \mathbb{P}(Y=1|X=x)$.

I am trying to evaluate the following Riemann-Stieltjes integral
$$ \int_{x'\beta \geq x_0'\beta} p(x) dF_X(x) $$
where $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^k$ are some coefficients, and $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^k$ is a fixed point.

If we were integrating over the entire support of $X$, then it is simply $\mathbb{E}_X[p(x)] = \mathbb{P}(Y=1)$ by Law of Iterated Expectations. However in this case, we constrain the region of integration to be $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^k : x'\beta \geq x_0'\beta\}$. Any suggestions on how to evaluate this integral?

Comment: it is $P(Y = 1, X'\beta \geq x_0'\beta)$.

Comment: Interesting. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Have you already worked with the general definition of conditional expectation? The "problem" here is that $\mathbb P(Y = 1 \vert X=x)$ is not well defined, because you cannot condition on events of measure 0 and $\{X = x\}$ cannot have positive probability for more than countably many $x$. Without the general definition of conditional probability, the problem is therefore not well-defined...

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the comment! I have not formally studied measure theory nor the general definition of conditional expectations, but your comment makes sense. In economics, it is common to denote something like $p(x) := \mathbb{P}(Y=1|X=x)$ as a (random) function of $X$. Perhaps this should be denoted more accurately as $p(X) = \mathbb{P}(Y=1|X) = \mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ since $Y$ is binary here. Would this make more sense?